# Why my textview is transparent when scrolling and how to disable it?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextview

I'm facing a weird problem here. I have a `UITextView` on the bottom of my View, and when the number of texts inside the UITextView exceeds the height of the textView, it will appear in the background of other items. Take a look at the pictures below.

I tried to change the position of the `text view` on top of `Nom` label (pic no. 2) but somehow only the `textFields` block/hide the texts in it when scrolled.

[image: viewController] 
[image: Structure of my view]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure your height constraints for your `UITextView` are set correctly.

Second of all, I strongly suggest you use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` for complex forms like these, as `UIScrollView` might not always be a good fit.

When using `UITableView` you can set the height of your elements to `.automaticDimension` so they transform with the height of their contents automatically and also reuse a lot of code such as headers and fields and make your form more modal and generic.

Comment: what i did was, i set the top constraint of the `textView` to the label above it and the bottom constraint to the `parent view`...so that the height will be flexible...is there any other alternative than using `UITableView`? @SergeyGrischyov

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the property `Clip to Bounds` is set to `true`. If it's set to `true` the extended content is shown beyond the control's bounds. I think that's the probability which is causing the content to show beyond your `UITextView` boundaries.

Comment: i already unset it but the problem still occurs :,( @GurdevSingh